# On MacOS perfect => On Windows a grey bottom border

Tags: css, javafx, background

I hope anyone can help ... we have written a little application in JavaFX.

This module has a

```
VBOX -> 
-ToolBar
-SplitPane ->
--AnchorPane
--AnchorPane
```

VBOX is set to 600px height. SplitPane and both AnchorPanes also.

**In MacOS X everything looks great - but in Windows there is a big, grey border at the bottom.**

I don't know which information I can give to solve this problem ... 
Please ask me if you need anything to know.

I have tested the SplitPane and the VBOX with a red background. But => Fail, the border was still grey.

Thanks! And please forgive my english writing ... I'm not native :)

Mac :

[image]

Windows :

[image]

Comment: Is the background color on the AnchorPane?

Comment: The green and blue color is on the AnchorPanes of the SplitPanes, yes. With CSS -fx-background-color ... 
And thanks for editing, I've got not enough points to post the images directly into the text.

Comment: My wildest guess would be that the AnchorPanes are not filling the SplitPanes. Btw, why do you need a SplitPane?

Comment: This is my first JavaFX Project ... you're right, now there is no need for a SplitPane. At the beginning of the project the hole AnchorPane of each side was filled with color. That was the reason for the SplitPane - to have 2 separated Panes.

Comment: Are you using two separate AnchorPane inside one SplitPane?

Comment: Yes. The VBOX height is 600px. 
The ToolBar height is 75px. 
The SplitPane height is 525px - and the height of the two AnchorPanes inside the SplitPane is also 525px.

Comment: Try and use `VBox.setVgrow(splitPane, Priority.ALWAYS);` on your splitPane. On fxml you can add `<SplitPane VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">`

Comment: You Sir ... are a genius! :)) 

Please set this last comment as an answer - so i can vote it as correct! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `SplitPane` is not able to cover the whole height of `VBox`. To force `SplitPane` to change its height when VBox changes its, use :

```
VBox.setVgrow(splitPane, Priority.ALWAYS);
```

In fxml you can achieve the same effect by adding :

```
<SplitPane VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
```